# Create a pandas column from nested list

Tags: python, pandas, list, nested-lists

How do i create a pandas column, where the lists inside my list become cells on their own? E.g.: I have the following nested list:

```
nested = [['1', '2', '3'],['2', '3', '1'],['3', '4'],['1']]
```

This list contains around 300 separate lists with strings of different length (min 1 max 5). Now i want to create a pandas dataframe column, where each of these lists in a single cell, not where each string is in a different cell. I tried it this way

```
df['new column'] = df[["col1", "col2"]].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
```

but it gives me an error messsage, because there are some None values, because the lists initially had different lengths.

Comment: Could you be clearer about the expected output?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([nested]).T` or more likely `df['new_column'] = pd.Series(nested)`?

Comment: The output should look like this: Dataframe with one column, each cell represents one list e.g. ['1', '2', '3',] is first cell, then ['2', '3', '1'] is second cell..

Comment: Thanks AChampion it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly this will be enough:

```
import pandas as pd

nested = [['1', '2', '3'], ['2', '3', '1'], ['3', '4'], ['1']]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': nested})
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
        col1
0  [1, 2, 3]
1  [2, 3, 1]
2     [3, 4]
3        [1]
```